# laravel 5.4 auth facade does not work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

The Laravel 5.4 Auth facade does not work.  The auth middleware functional normally.  A call to a protected route produces the login page, as expected.  Malformed credentials produce the expected error.  Correct credentials produce the correct page, as expected.  Commenting out the line "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;" produces the error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth' not found", as expected.

Specifically, Auth::check() produces false, and Auth::user() returns nothing, in spite of a successful login.  Calls to either of these implementations of the Auth facade does not produce an error.

This code worked well in Laravel 5.2.  The only deviation from procedure of which I am aware is that during the migration to Laravel 5.4, I did not run the command "php artisan make:auth" in a new Laravel implementation.

A search for "laravel 5.4 auth facade does not work" does not produce relevant results, either in Bing or in the stackoverflow internal search engine.

Pertinent code is displayed, below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Models\Admin;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Role_user;
use App\Models\Client;
use App\Models\Contact;
use App\Models\PublicPages;
use App\Models\Survey_question;
use App\Models\Survey_item;
use App\Models\Survey_project;
use App\Models\State;
use App\Models\Test_post;
use App\Models\Registration;
use Hash;
use Redirect;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Classes\RoleHelper;
use App\Classes\CommonCode;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
var $obj_logged_in_user;
var $arr_logged_in_user;
var $bool_has_role;
var $roleHelper;
//organization of function
// 1. __construct
// 2. index
// get, alphabetically
// post, alphabetically

public function __construct(
        Role_user $role_user, RoleHelper $roleHelper, Request 
$request)
{   

    $this->middleware('auth');
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "admin controller, line 50<br>";
    print_r($request->user);
    echo "</pre>";
    // line 49 (request->user) produces nothing

    if (Auth::check())
    {

        $this->middleware('role:admin');
        $this->obj_logged_in_user = Auth::user();
print_r($this->obj_logged_in_user);
// line 58 (print_r) produces nothing
        $this->arr_logged_in_user = $roleHelper->prepare_logged_in_user_info($this->obj_logged_in_user);

    }  // end if Auth::check()

} // end __construct function
```

In conclusion, I would like for Auth::check() to return accurate results, and for Auth::user() to return the logged in user object.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't use it in the constructor, the middlewares didn't even run at this point in time.

Comment: Sessions are not set in middleware and therefore neither would the User off of the Auth facade. This is not the right way to use controllers, it's an example of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Auth` functions inside your `__construct()` method then you need to pass it to `$this->middleware()` inside a closure.

```
public function __construct(Role_user $role_user, RoleHelper $roleHelper)
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('role:admin');
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) use ($role_user, $roleHelper) {

        if (Auth::check()) {

            $this->obj_logged_in_user = Auth::user();
            $this->arr_logged_in_user = $roleHelper->prepare_logged_in_user_info($this->obj_logged_in_user);

        }  

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Also, just an FYI, you might find it easier to use the `dump()` or `dd()` functions that come with Laravel. Instead of writing:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "admin controller, line 50<br>";
print_r($request->user);
echo "</pre>";
```

you could instead write:

```
dump('admin controller, line 50', $request->user);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd

Hope this helps!

Comment: But if you set the auth middleware, it will redirect the user if they are not logged in. Is there any way to check if a user is logged in, WITHOUT redirecting them automatically?

Comment: @Benubird Just don't include the `$this->middleware('auth');` bit (and most likely the `role:admin` bit as well).

Comment: If you leave off the middleware, then Auth::user returns null and Auth::check returns false

Comment: @Benubird This is to be expected if you don't have a logged in user.